# How can I preserve dynamic import statements with babel preset env?

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, dynamic-import

I am creating shared modules that contain dynamic imports for code splitting.

I have code like:

```js
import('./moduleA').then(/* do stuff */)
```

However babel compiles this to a deferred require which stops Webpack from code splitting.

The transformed result looks like:

```js
Promise.resolve().then(() => require('./moduleA')).then(/* do stuff */)
```

My `.babelrc.json` is simple and only contains:

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

How can I preserve the dynamic imports in my babel transformed code?

Answer (score 13):

This is happening because `@babel/preset-env` by default includes a plugin, `@babel/plugin-proposal-dynamic-import`, that transforms dynamic imports.

There are two ways to stop this.

### Option One (recommended)

You can exclude the plugin `@babel/plugin-proposal-dynamic-import` so the `import()` statements stay untouched. Update your preset options with the following:

```
{
  "presets": [["@babel/preset-env", { "exclude": ["proposal-dynamic-import"] }]]
}
```

### Option Two

In the preset options add `"modules": false`, however this will also preserve ES module import/export statements.

```
{
  "presets": [["@babel/preset-env", { "modules": false }]]
}
```

---

This is described in depth in these GitHub Issues:

- https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/11204
- https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/10194